# XML Error - Premature end of data in tag widgets line 3 Line: 40

Tags: layout, xml

I have looked over a few times and cant see any tags that are not closed so im lost on whats wrong. I am new to XML and would love the help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:ZaniboniCustom:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Block\Widget\ProductGrid" id="ZaniboniCustom_productWidget">
    <label>Product Widget</label>
    <description>Show Products</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_sort_by" xsi:type="select" visible="true" source_model="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Model\SortBy">
                <label translate="true">Sort Products By</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_sort_order" xsi:type="select" visible="true" source_model="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Model\SortOrder">
                <label translate="true">Sort Products Order</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="show_pager" xsi:type="select" visible="true" source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Display Page Control</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_per_page" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true" source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products per Page</label>
                <depends>
                    <parameter name="show_pager" value="1" />
                </depends>
                <value>5</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_count" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products to Display</label>
                <value>10</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="default" value="Magento_catalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
                        <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an issue with the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`

use this below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Block\Widget\ProductGrid" id="ZaniboniCustom_productWidget">
        <label>Product Widget</label>
        <description>Show Products</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_sort_by" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
                       source_model="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Model\SortBy">
                <label translate="true">Sort Products By</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_sort_order" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
                       source_model="ZaniboniCustom\productWidget\Model\SortOrder">
                <label translate="true">Sort Products Order</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="show_pager" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
                       source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Display Page Control</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_per_page" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true"
                       source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products per Page</label>
                <depends>
                    <parameter name="show_pager" value="1"/>
                </depends>
                <value>5</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_count" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products to Display</label>
                <value>10</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="default" value="Magento_catalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml"
                            selected="true">
                        <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: that works and got rid of the error but now I have a new issue where the options dont actually display on the widget menu... the label and description shows but now the parameters

Comment: refer magento's catalog module `widget.xml` that may help you to design your own widget or else post new question with all code.